# How to sort an IQueryable object dynamically with an expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I have a custom datagridview where the user can browse true it's pages with buttons like next, previous, first and last.

In the generic part of the code I have the following IQueryable object: `IQueryable iqRetVal = iqData;`. Its contents is dynamically filled by other forms and it could contain for example users and the next time companies (So there is no way of knowing beforehand what will be in it.).

This is the code for `iqData`:

```
IQueryable iqData = null;
public IQueryable Data //this is how iqData is filled.
{
    get { return iqData; }
    set
    {
        iqData = value;
        RefreshDataGridView();
    }
}
```

Now I know what the user previously clicked on based on 2 variables:

```
private SortOrder sortOrder; //The sort order like ascending or descending
private DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn; the column that was sorted on.
```

This is the error message that my code gives:

> No generic method OrderByDescending in type System.Linq.Queryable is
>   compateble with the given typearguments and arguments. No
>   typearguments must ge given if the method is not generic.

The code itself:

```
try
{
    if (dataGridViewColumn != null)
    {
        var propName = dataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName;
        ParameterExpression param = null;

        foreach (var item in iqRetVal)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                param = Expression.Parameter(item.GetType(), string.Empty);
                break;
            }
        }
        MemberExpression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propName);
        LambdaExpression sort = Expression.Lambda(property, param);

        if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            iqRetVal = iqRetVal.Provider.CreateQuery(Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { iqRetVal.ElementType }, iqRetVal.Expression, Expression.Quote(sort)));
        }
        else
        {
            iqRetVal = iqRetVal.Provider.CreateQuery(Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { iqRetVal.ElementType }, iqRetVal.Expression, Expression.Quote(sort)));
        }

    }
    else { }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

What exactly am I missing to make my code work? Because I have searched for a long time but it seems like most answers don’t offer the answer I’m looking for.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `ParameterExpression param= Expression.Parameter(iqRetVal.GetType(), string.Empty);`? It will be overwritten by the next few lines, won't it?

Comment: and please try `typeof(IQueryable<>)`instead of `typeof(Queryable)`. `typeof(Queryable)`  implies a non generic type but you are passing type parameters.

Comment: @JosefBiehler When I write `IQueryable<>` insead of  `Queryable` it returns the following error: There is no method called OrderByDescending in type System.Linq.IQueryable`1[T].

Comment: @JosefBiehler, there is indeed no need for param to be assign so early so i updated my code and made it null. Also I missed a break in the foreach loop so i added that too. Unfortunately this does not change and/or solve my question and problem.

Comment: @Morganis: Hoorah! Glad I helped. You now have an answer. Also as an aside your `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` seem to be the wrong way round.

Comment: @Morganis: Given that most of the useful stuff I put in comments is not in my answer I'm going to go through and delete all my old comments to make the question a bit tidier. Just letting you know since this may make some of your comments not make sense and thus be prime candidates for deletion too.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I will delete my comments too in that case. (including this one once you deleted yours). By the way, Thank you for telling my Orderby and OrderByDescending are the other way arround. Changed that in my code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method call causing problems is this:

```
Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { iqRetVal.ElementType }, iqRetVal.Expression, Expression.Quote(sort));
```

Looking at the [documentation for this overload of CreateQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Type_System_String_System_Type___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression___) we can see that the first parameter is the type that contains the static method, the second is the method name, the third is the generic parameters needed by that method and the subsequent items are the parameters to the method.

The `OrderBy` method does exist on `Queryable` so our first two paramters are good. If we [look at this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_OrderBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) though then we see that it has *two* generic parameters: `OrderBy<TSource,TKey>`. Currently we are only passing one type. This makes sense of the error message which says the type arguments are incorrect.

So our first type is the type of the Queryable which we are correctly getting as `iqRetVal.ElementType`. The second is the type of key that our sort selector returns. This can be found using `sort.ReturnType`.

So this would then make the method call look like this:

```
Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { iqRetVal.ElementType, sort.ReturnType }, iqRetVal.Expression, Expression.Quote(sort))
```